# Get div overflowing outside of realtive div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following example, I want the `goOutside` div (the yellow one) will overflow out of the relative div. but to keep the scrolling inside the relative div (by the content of the div).

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}  

.content {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
  
.goOutside {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="goOutside">
    
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you still want answer about select and model?

Comment: @לבנימלכהI simplified my question, this is still related to the previous question.

Comment: @לבנימלכה i want the yellow div will start from inside the relative div and will go outside the relative div. think about it like this is simple HTML option element and I want my options to be showed and not hidden inside the relative div.

Comment: I get you... but see here when I put select:https://jsfiddle.net/0mcdgae7/

Comment: I don't understand the request, maybe you want something like [http://cssdeck.com/labs/qo4x6w0i](this)?

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra the link you attached not available

Comment: @לבנימלכהI don't want the select element, the `goOutside` div need to go outside the relative div. this is a tricky question.

Comment: Sorry, try now --> http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/qo4x6w0i

Comment: @NirBerko : what about it:https://jsfiddle.net/0mcdgae7/1/

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra this is given to me what I want, but I am looking for a solution without using any js.

Comment: I think that this cannot be done with CSS only, I'm sorry.

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra this is what i thout also, but i think your solution will do the job. thanks you DanieleAlessandra! i will update here if i will have any problem.